# Why is my EntityManagerFactory in a ServletContextListener causing a 404 error?

Tags: tomcat, jpa, servlets, entitymanager, weblistener

When I try to access my Login page http://localhost:8181/InaalEchtok/Login I get the following error message:

> HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /InaalEchtok/Login
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M20

With no error message on my eclipse console.
After trying many other things, I understood that what is causing the error is the EntityManagerFactory that I'm trying to create in a `@WebListener`.

This is the code of the WebListener:

```
@WebListener
public class CustomServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();

    entityManagerFactory = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();

    //entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("model_persistence_unit");
    context.setAttribute("emf", entityManagerFactory);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
    sc.removeAttribute("emf");
}
}
```

I've tried to set the entityManagerFactory in two different ways, one of them is commented out.  The first way is what works for any other purpose except in the WebListener.
Both ways cause the error.
I'm sure that that is what causes the problem because when IO comment out both lines:

```
entityManagerFactory = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();

entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("model_persistence_unit");
```

the error does not occur (but then I don't have any access to my DB).

This is my web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>InaalEchtok</display-name>
    <!-- <listener>
        <listener-class>server.servlets.CustomServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener> -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Although, if I'm not mistaken, it has nothing to do with the error because I'm using the `@WebListener` annotation.  That's why I commented the `<listener>......</listener>` out.
(also when it's not commented out the error keeps on appearing)

My persistence.xml is saved in `WebContent\META-INF` and as mentioned before, works for any other purpose except of in the `@WebListener`.

Thank you for your time!

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="model_persistence_unit">
        <description>Persistence unit for the JPA tutorial of the Hibernate Getting Started Guide</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!-- <class></class> -->

        <properties>
            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" /> -->
            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/> -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="****" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="********" />


            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: here's an idea ... you debug the call to those methods and see what exception is thrown by them, and then from that exception you resolve why the exception is thrown

Comment: Well, I feel stupid...

Comment: Well, I feel stupid...When I ran the page in chrome, it didn't show anything in the console, but now that I ran the servlet from Eclipse, I got a message telling me I'm missing a jar. So I added it, but now I'm getting a message telling me `Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.` although I for sure have that declaration (as I wrote, I've been working with that persistence.xml for a while now)..